# Too much content. Too little space

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design

Images and text to be placed in a limited space are too many and unrelated. I can't tell what to do.
What can I try as a UX designer when I can't determine the size of the space and what needs to be done?

Comment: Do you have some screenshots to illustrate your question? It could be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to UXSE. Your question is a common challenge that all designers have to deal with, but with some examples you might be able to elicit a more detailed response to your specific problem. A common strategy is to design for both the best and worst case scenario, and be flexible in your overall layout and content organisation. That way, as the requirements and constraints change, you can also adjust your design accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

When you have too much content and little space, you should categorize your content and make a separate page for each content category. Besides, you need knowledge of an **information architect**. you can start **card sorting** or alternative options and categorize your content based on users minds.